# No way to migrate to Spanish Stack Overflow?

Tags: feature-request, migration

After coming across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40807535/abrir-nueva-ventana-scene-desde-button-javafx) today, I saw there was no way to flag it to be migrated to [Spanish Stack Overflow](https://es.stackoverflow.com/). Instead there were comments asking him/her to translate their question to English.

This seems a bit silly to me. Why have him/her go through the work of translating every comment, question, answer, etc., when there's a whole site for Spanish questions.

Basically, my question is, why is there no way to flag a question to have it migrated to the Spanish version of Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a fixed number of migration target slots available in the migration UI: four other sites plus the current site's meta. The migration paths are chosen to maximize their usefulness. For example, it wouldn't be useful to Super User to have a migration path to Bicycles; we get infinitesimally few if any questions that would benefit from that.

Likewise, Stack Overflow doesn't get all that many questions written in foreign languages, at least not as many as are off-topic and better suited for its current migration targets. However, moderators of a site can instantly migrate a question *anywhere*. Therefore, if the question is high-quality (poor questions shouldn't be migrated), you can cast a custom mod flag asking the moderators to move it to es.SO. In this case, though my Spanish is not super great, I suspect the question would be closed as unclear/broad if migrated.

Comment: As a regular [es.so] user, I can almost guarantee that question would be closed as unclear.